# ggplot inside renderPlot cannot recognise input$myvariable

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a ggplot inside of a renderPlot function. This code block works as expected:

```
output$revenue_channel <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(untrended_data(), aes(x = reorder(Channel, Revenue), y = Revenue), label = Revenue) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "#008080", alpha = 0.6) +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::dollar(Revenue)), hjust= 1.2, color = "white") +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::label_dollar(scale = 0.001, suffix = "K")) +
    xlab("") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
}, height = 300)
```

This code block as is runs and produces this chart:
[image]

But, in my I actually have a breakdown selector where the user ca enter one of Channel, Device or UserType.

So, this line:

```
ggplot(untrended_data(), aes(x = reorder(Channel, Revenue), y = Revenue), label = Revenue)
```

Would become either this:

```
ggplot(untrended_data(), aes(x = reorder(Device, Revenue), y = Revenue), label = Revenue)
```

Or this:

```
ggplot(untrended_data(), aes(x = reorder(UserType, Revenue), y = Revenue), label = Revenue)
```

I tried just switching in `input$myinput` like so

```
ggplot(untrended_data(), aes(x = reorder(input$breakdown, Revenue), y = Revenue), label = Revenue)
```

But this gives an error:

> Error: arguments must have same length

I then tried aes_ for aes_string():

```
ggplot(untrended_data(), aes_(x = reorder(input$breakdown, "Revenue"), y = "Revenue"), label = Revenue)
```

> Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I then tried t make sense of [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) page on quasi-quotation and tried:

```
ggplot(untrended_data(), aes(x = reorder(!! input$breakdown, Revenue), y = Revenue), label = Revenue)
```

Which resulted in:

> Error: arguments must have same length

How can I pass input$breakdown into ggplot within `renderPlot({})`?

Comment: Can you try `reorder(!! rlang::sym(input$breakdown), Revenue),`

Comment: It works! Thank you. I was really struggling there. What does rlang::sym() do? Actually, I've struggled to really understand quosures and tidy eval

Comment: The input is a string, so we are converting to symbol and evaluating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input$breakdown` stores a string as value, and if we convert it to a `sym`bol (using `rlang::sym`) and then evaluate (`!!`) it would work, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
v1 <- "mpg";
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = reorder(!! rlang::sym(v1), cyl), y = cyl, label = cyl))+
     geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "#008080", alpha = 0.6) + 
    coord_flip()
```

---

In the OP's code block, we need to use `reorder(!! rlang::sym(input$breakdown), Revenue)`

```
output$revenue_channel <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(untrended_data(), aes(x = reorder(!! rlang::sym(input$breakdown), Revenue),
          y = Revenue), label = Revenue) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "#008080", alpha = 0.6) +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::dollar(Revenue)), hjust= 1.2, color = "white") +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::label_dollar(scale = 0.001, suffix = "K")) +
    xlab("") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
}, height = 300)
```